# Error creating bean EntityFactoryManager on a new project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

So I have a project I want to start work with. The senior developer sent me a zip package of the project and database.sql file for initializing the local database for me to just launch the project. But we are facing the error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

All entities are exactly the same as in the local database. I have changed the XML file config to match my password and URL. Spend 2 days trying to run the project. Will appreciate any help. Please feel free to ask any questions.

```
 <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- Set JPA properties -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.ProgressDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="nl.impressie.grazer.hibernate" />
    </bean>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like hibernate is failing to initialize due to a failure to connect to the DB.

Are you sure you have a Postgresql DB running? Is Spring configured correctly to interface with that DB? (i.e. is the host, port, databaseschema, username and password set?)

Comment: yes, i just double checked every properties and xml file, all match my local DB

Answer (score 0):

If this is a *new* project, you shouldn't be using any of this XML configuration at all. Instead, create a template project at https://start.spring.io that includes the JPA starter, set your `spring.datasource.url`, and be running in 2 minutes.

Comment: people have already worked on the project for several years, for me its new because i just starting working on it

Comment: also we dont you spring boot, just spring mvc